# How can I get first line in SQL using groupby in laravel 8?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to always get the first line in a group.

**My code:**

```
public function getLast(){
    $etats = EtatTerminal::orderBy('id','desc')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('Android_id' )
    ;
  return response($etats, 200);
  }
```

The result always gives me the grouped lines(which is what I want). After getting the grouped lines, I want to be able to use first() with groupby() to search the lines. When I use the functions, however, they don't return anything.

```
{
    "c1ba5fbd480c1e00": [
        {
            "id": 96,
            "Android_id": "c1ba5fbd480c1e00",
            "NiveauDeBatterie": "34%",
            "Memoire": "832045056 Kb",
            "Lattitude": null,
            "Longitude": null,
            "Fabriquant": "HUAWEI",
            "Modele": "DRA-LX2",
            "VersionSE": "8.1.0",
            "created_at": "2021-06-09T22:19:05.403000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-09T22:19:05.403000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 95,
            "Android_id": "c1ba5fbd480c1e00",
            "NiveauDeBatterie": "34%",
            "Memoire": "845262848 Kb",
            "Lattitude": null,
            "Longitude": null,
            "Fabriquant": "HUAWEI",
            "Modele": "DRA-LX2",
            "VersionSE": "8.1.0",
            "created_at": "2021-06-09T22:18:54.180000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-09T22:18:54.180000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved

```
    $etats = EtatTerminal::orderByDesc('id')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('Android_id');
    $numItems = count($etats);
    $i=0;
    $data = array();
    foreach ($etats  as $etat) {
      if(++$i !== $numItems+1) {
        $data []=$etat[0];
    }}
    return response($data, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only get the first model/data after a group by, do everything in the database, do not do `->get()->groupBy` as that `groupBy` is going to be run on PHP, and that could take a lot of time, let the database handle that in microseconds instead of milliseconds (and memory)...

So, try this:

```php
public function getLast(){
    $etats = EtatTerminal::select('max(id) as id', '*')
        ->groupBy('Android_id')
        ->orderByDesc('id')
        ->first();

    return response($etats);
}
```

If this did not help you, please comment a little more what you exactly want as I am not 100% sure.

Comment: i tried this but this error always given to me
lluminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'etat_terminals.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (SQL: select top 1 * from [etat_terminals] group by [Android_id] order by [id] desc) in file D:\Epi\PFE\code\backpfe\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 685

Comment: for more explication, i just like to get the first line of all android_id, juste the first

Comment: Oh, so you are using `SQL Server`... when you say "first line of all android_id", do you mean you want to get only the most recent `android_id` ?

Comment: yes i use `SQL SERVER` and i want to get the most recent record of an android_id

Comment: I have no idea if this is going to work but try `EtatTerminal::select('id', 'Android_id')->orderByDesc...` and see if that helps

Comment: so, that's not what i want, all i want the most recent record of all the android_id.

Comment: same error ``Column 'etat_terminals.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (SQL: select top 1 [id], * from [etat_terminals] group by [Android_id] order by [id] desc) in file D:\Epi\PFE\code\backpfe\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 685``

Comment: i think that laravel don't accept first() with groupby() !!

Comment: Laravel is not the problem, SQL Server is. It works with MySQL. Try a new query, see my updated answer again.

Comment: it works this time, but i won't get the recent record of all my table just i like to group this information by android_id and get the recent record, because i have many etat_terminals in one table ;)

Comment: Okay, let's do one last try, see update again

Comment: well, it's the same problem, thx for your effort :)